# Partials in TypeScript getters/setters

Tags: angular, typescript, getter-setter

In Angular I allow a component input for setting options, say of type `IOptions`
In the setter it doesn't have to be complete as it will be merged with default options, so it is typed as `Partial<IOptions>`.

```
const DEFAULT_OPTIONS = { prop1: false, prop2: 123 };

export class MyComponent {
  _options: IOptions;

  get options(): IOptions {
    return this._options;
  }

  @Input('config')
  set options(userOptions: Partial<IOptions>) {
    this._options = { ...DEFAULT_OPTIONS, ...userOptions };
  }
}
```

The getter on the other hand is always expected to return a complete, not partial, object, so the type is `IOptions`. But the compiler complains about getter and setter not having identical types. How do I solve it?

Comment: remove the `Partial<>`

Comment: You can't really do that, the getter and setter should have the same type. You can create a `setOptions` method.

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir That's correct. Sadly, setOptions won't work well with Angular data binding.

Comment: Removing `Partial<>` is kind of an answer in that it does solve the problem, but it contradicts what Partial is meant for (or at least how I understand its purpose).

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it in Typescript, since getter and setter should be same type, so you can change all to `Partial<IOptions>` or

there is another solution for your original requirement

define your option as class with optional properties and default values, like below

```
export class MyComponentOption {
   prop1?: boolean = false;
   prop2?: number = 123;

   constructor(params: MyComponentOption ) {
     Object.assign(this, params)
   }
}
```

then

```
export class MyComponent {
  @Input('config') options : MyComponentOption;
}
```

and this is how you can set it with some params

```
config:MyComponentOption = new MyComponentOption({prop1:true});
```